# std::function of a value templated method compiles with clang and g++ but not with msvc

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, visual-c++, clang

The following code [compiles with clang v5.0.0](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ff4ac7c4a2de8432) and [g++ v8.1.0](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0c68940b11689d38) but fails with visual studio (2013 and 2017):

```
#include <string>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

template <const char* name>
std::string fct() {
   return name;
}

const char toto[] = "toto";
std::function<std::string()> fctptr = fct<toto>;

int main(){
   std::cout << fctptr() << std::endl;
}
```

The error is the following:

```
main.cpp(11): error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'std::string (__cdecl *)(void)' to 'std::function<std::string (void)>'
1>          No constructor could take the source type, or constructor overload resolution was ambiguous
```

I tried to replace the std::function with a typedef to a function pointer, as such:

```
typedef std::string(*Fctptr)();
Fctptr fctptr = fct<toto>;
```

However, I got the same error.

Is it a bug with msvc compiler, or is the above code not standard compliant.

Comment: The problem has to do with using an array implicitly converted to a pointer as a template argument.

Comment: Possibly for use as template parameter MSVC requires an `extern` linkage pointer known at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, the following failed to compile using g++  6.4.0 (`g++ -std=c++11`).

```
#include <string>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

template <const char* name>
std::string fct() {
   return name;
}

const char toto[] = "toto";
std::function<std::string()> fctptr = fct<toto>;

int main(){
   std::cout << fctptr() << std::endl;
}
```

Here's the error message:

```
socc.cc:11:43: error: the value of ‘toto’ is not usable in a constant expression
 std::function<std::string()> fctptr = fct<toto>;
                                           ^~~~
socc.cc:10:12: note: ‘toto’ was not declared ‘constexpr’
 const char toto[] = "toto";
```

Changing the definition of `toto` to

```
constexpr char toto[] = "toto";
```

resolved the problem.